# Need help understanding nested functions in javascript

Tags: jquery

I have the following functions written in jQuery. It grabs a HTML table and outputs a cvs file. I don't understand nested functions (i.e. using function within a function). it looks very confusing. is it normal to code JavaScript like this?
Would it be possible for anyone to re-write this in separate functions so I can understand it better?

For example in "function (i, row)" where are the values passes to the function as "i" and "row"?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
            colDelim = '","',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                var $row = $(row),
                    $cols = $row.find('td');

                return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col),
                        text = $col.text();

                    return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

            }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

            // Data URI
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        $(this)
            .attr({
            'download': filename,
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank'
        });
    }

    // This must be a hyperlink
    $(".export").on('click', function (event) {
        // CSV
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the jQuery API for the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function.

**Quote:**

> Type: Function( Integer index, Element domElement ) => Object
>
> A function object that will be invoked for each element in the current set.

In the code you've supplied, you have a jQuery object that is created using the code:

```
var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)');
```

The `$rows` jQuery object contains a number of results. The [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function applies a transformation to that object, and when that API is called, **jQuery passes these parameters for you to use in the callback**.

So inside your callback `i` is the index of the item in the collection, and `row` is the element at that position.

Comment: got it, could you just tell me where in "i" and "row" passed to the function at line 17?

Comment: right, function takes in "i" and "row, but where in this code are those values passed in to the function?

Comment: They're passed by the `map()` function when it calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are passed internally by the `.map()` method. In a much simplified form, it works something like this:

```
map: function(callback) {
    var results = [];
    for (var index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
        results.push(callback(index, this[index]));
    }
    return $(results);
}
```

Comment: why isn't it coded this way then? is it more professional that way?

Comment: You could write this yourself. It's a convenience function to make it easier for you.